# StackNavigator menu not aligning on the left

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, native-base

I am trying to implement the react stack navigator in my expo app. The app is working perfectly fine except the drawer menu icon which is not being displayed on the left as it was supposedly to be. Can anyone tell me where I messed up?

Here is the screenshot of the app
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7M2e5.jpg)

Here is my App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, ScrollView, Dimensions, Image } from 'react-native';

import {createDrawerNavigator,DrawerItems} from 'react-navigation'

import SplashScreen from './src/components/splash';
import LibraryScreen from './src/screens/LibraryScreen';
import ReminderScreen from './src/screens/ReminderScreen';
import ReportScreen from './src/screens/ReportScreen';
import SettingsScreen from './src/screens/SettingsScreen';
import TrainingScreen from './src/screens/TrainingScreen';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppDrawerNavigator/>
    );
  }
}

const CustomDrawerComponent = (props) =>(
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex:1 }}>
    <View style={{ height:150, backgroundColor: 'white',alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center' }}>
      <Image source={require('./assets/icon.png')} style={{ height:120, width: 120, borderRadius:60 }} />
    </View>
    <ScrollView>
      <DrawerItems {...props} />
    </ScrollView>
  </SafeAreaView>
)

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Training:TrainingScreen,
  Library:LibraryScreen,
  Report:ReportScreen,
  Reminder:ReminderScreen,
  Settings:SettingsScreen
},{
  contentComponent:CustomDrawerComponent
})

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

And this is the Training.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import {header,Left,Right,Icon, Header} from 'native-base'

class TrainingScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header>
          <Left>
            <Icon name="menu" onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}/>
          </Left>
        </Header>
        <View style={{flex:1, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
          <Text>Training Screen</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default TrainingScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

Comment: Would you be able to share it on snack.expo.io? for a faster answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add below style in your code it works. Add this style <**Left style={{justifyContent:"flex-start",flex:1}}**> in your code

**Training.js**

```
  class TrainingScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header >
          <Left style={{justifyContent:"flex-start",flex:1}}><---Update---
            <Icon
              name="menu"
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}
            />
          </Left>
        </Header>
        <View
          style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}
        >
          <Text>Training Screen</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default TrainingScreen;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to include all `Left`, `Body`, and `Right` in your NativeBase `Header`

```js
<Header>
  <Left>
    <Icon name="menu" onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}/>
  </Left>
  <Body/>
  <Right/>
</Header>
```